# Correct way to set/unset a rewrite for an URL programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to rewrite URLs of products if they are out of stock. I want to do this by using an observer.

How can I set a URL rewrite and how can I unset it programmitcally? I want to utilize the core functions to do that.

Bonus points if you can provide a backend view for viewing and editing those rewrites.

Answer (score 2):

Use **observer and watching the event** `controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view`.

Declare observer in `config.xml`

```
<events>
            <controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
                <observers>
                    <system_controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_view>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>YOU EXTENSION NAME/observer</class>
                        <method>catalogProductViewPredispatch</method>
                    </system_controller_action_postdispatch_catalog_product_view>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view>
</events>
```

And add this method to `../Models/Observer.php`

```
public function catalogProductViewPredispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        Varien_Profiler::start(__METHOD__);

        $product_id = intval(Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
        $_product   = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product')->load($product_id);

        if(! $_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()) {
            $redirect_url='<Your redirect URL>';
            Mage::app()->getResponse()
                       ->setRedirect($redirect_url, 302);
        }


        Varien_Profiler::stop(__METHOD__);
    }
```

Comment: Will test and give you feedback asap. One question beforehand: how could I possibly set the redirect URL to the products FIRST category URL?

Comment: @Max what do you mean by  products FIRST category URL ? Product can be in multiple categories

Answer (score 0):

You can use controller_action_predispatch_catalog_product_view event for product view page. Check product is out of stock or not and redirect to required url if the product is out of stock.

Comment: Could you specify a little more?